# How to duplicate auto-random color generated square using same style and function

Tags: html, function, dom, colors, duplicates

Even I tried to find an answer I didn't found the exactly information (until now).
I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html personal exercise>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>An DOM example project</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.005">
        <style>
            div {position:absolute; margin-left:100px};
        </style>
    </head>
        <body id="theBody" onload="show_pattern()">
            <script>
                function show_pattern() {
                    var top_position=25, left_position=25;
                    var width=500, height=500;
                    var color_list=["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
                    var the_body=document.getElementById("theBody");

                    while(width>50) {
                        var this_div=document.createElement("div");
                        var random_color=Math.random()*7;
                        random_color=Math.floor(random_color);
                        this_div.style.top=top_position + "px";
                        this_div.style.left=left_position + "px";
                        this_div.style.width=width + "px";
                        this_div.style.height=height + "px";
                        this_div.style.background=color_list[random_color];
                        the_body.appendChild(this_div);
                        top_position += 10; left_position += 10;
                        width -= 20; height -= 20;}}
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

I want to display on same page two colored squares using same function (show_pattern()) and div style.

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append a `for` loop and create within it wrapping divs for colored squares

```js
function show_pattern() {
        var color_list=["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
        var the_body=document.getElementById("theBody");
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){   
            var width=500, height=500, top_position=25, left_position=25;
            var wrap_div=document.createElement("div");
            wrap_div.className="wrap";
            wrap_div.style.left=500*i + "px";
            the_body.appendChild(wrap_div);
        while(width>50) {
            var this_div=document.createElement("div");
            var random_color=Math.random()*7;
            random_color=Math.floor(random_color);
            this_div.style.top=top_position + "px";
            this_div.style.left=left_position + "px";
            this_div.style.width=width + "px";
            this_div.style.height=height + "px";
            this_div.style.background=color_list[random_color];
            wrap_div.appendChild(this_div);
            top_position += 10; left_position += 10;
            width -= 20;
            height -= 20;
        }
   }
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
.wrap div {
    position: absolute;
}
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body id="theBody" onload="show_pattern()">
        </body>
```

Comment: Thank you Banzay for your help and fast response :-) !

Comment: I followed the code and it works fine. Can you help me please to set up only the second square (wrap) in a specific position to be completely separated from first square?

Comment: I've changed answer. is it what you need?

Comment: Thank you Banzay! With this changes the code works fine. :-) I'm a beginner and I still learning the basics.